# Applying json data to format style via jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have an odd problem with the following:

```
function loadTextbox(jsonUrl,divId){
    $.getJSON(jsonUrl, function(json) {
        $('#' + divId).html('<h2>'+json.heading+'</h2>');
        alert(json.config.headingConfig);
        $('#' + divId).children().css(json.config.headingConfig);
    })
}
```

The alert above returns: {color: 'white', fontFamily:'Arial, Times, serif'} However, the format of the text does not change.

Now here is the odd part: If I do this:

```
function loadTextbox(jsonUrl,divId){
        $.getJSON(jsonUrl, function(json) {
            $('#' + divId).html('<h2>'+json.heading+'</h2>');
            alert(json.config.headingConfig);
            $('#' + divId).children().css({color: 'white', fontFamily:'Arial, Times, serif'});
        })
    }
```

It works fine... The text format is Arial font and white. I am baffled... which probably means there is a very simple answer, any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your `json.config.headingConfig` contains a JSON *string*.

You need to convert it to an actual object by calling `$.parseJSON`.

Comment: Like this: $('#' + divId).children().css($.parseJSON(json.config.headingConfig));

When I do this, it gives me the following error: Uncaught Invalid JSON: {color: 'white', fontFamily:'Arial, Times, serif'}

Comment: @Yotta: You can either change it to valid JSON (with `"` everywhere) or call `eval`.